# Meteor, too many Kadira fetched document

Tags: meteor, kadira

I've developed a very simple app with Meteor, it permits to edit data online. It's not public available and it is used by 2-3 persons. So for simplicity I have create a single global subscription that returns all collections like these:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    // this template will be rendered until the subscriptions are ready
    loadingTemplate: 'spinner',
    waitOn: function () {

        // return one handle, a function, or an array
        return[
            Meteor.subscribe('allcollection1'),
            Meteor.subscribe('allcollection2'),
            Meteor.subscribe('allcollection3'),
            Meteor.subscribe('allcollection4'),
            Meteor.subscribe('allcollection5'),
            Meteor.subscribe('allcollection6'),

            ]
    }
});
```

I know it's not good to publish all documents, but they are less than 10k documents and they are deeply connected, load time is about 5 seconds but after that it's very fast.

I've integrated Kadira(free plan) to this app and watching Live Queries I see that the fetched documents where more than 200k. I expected to be always less than 10k. How could it be possible?  (server side no oplog available)

Comment: Probably because you subscribe on router. It will resubscribe whenever router change

Comment: It's same thing that I thought but I've seen this kind of code also in Discover Meteor.